# BGE python: accessing Edge information in a mesh made of polylines (not polygons)

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine, edges

In the Blender Game Engine I need to know if two vertexes are connected by and edge. However, the mesh is made of polylines (segments), not polygons, thus I can not use KX_MeshProxy.getPolygon(index). How can I access this information? The mesh in the picture is not the one I use, it is just an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The BGE does not know edges. The BGE knows polygons (faces) which are defined by 3 or 4 vertices.

An edge in this context is a semantic interpretation of a line between two vertices. It does not exist as object nor is it used anywhere. The render engine simply does not need it.

You need to know in the BGE the faces do not necessarily share the same vertices even when in Blender it seams like that.

**I can give you a general guideline:**

- Iterate over the polygons of the mesh.
- A polygon has 3 or 4 vertices. An "virtual" edge are two consecutive vertices plus the edge between the last and the first vertex. You will get as many edges as the polygon has vertices
- Now you should have all edges (with begin and end vertices) of all polygons.
- You can match them to each other by comparing the vertex positions. Be aware edges have a direction. You need to consider the reverse of an edge when comparing.

Comment: My mesh has no faces, it is made of consecutive segments, but they never close up, thus they do not form any face. Does this mean that the mesh is ignored by the game engine?

Comment: If it is visible you get faces (as this is what you see). Otherwise you can try to access the vertices from the mesh via Python. If they are not there, you can't uses them. - just did a test - you need faces to get the vertices.

Comment: It is interesting why you think you need this sort of object in your game. (there might be other ways to handle your situation).

Comment: I use it as a graph for pathfinding. I can derive the graph from a mesh (one point of the graph for each face of the mesh) but this needs more calculation.

Comment: Also, in my particular case, it is more complex to handle the mesh in a way that the generated graph is what I want. I need a graph that resembles the taxiways signs of an airport (yellow lines that you can see in any airport using google maps). However, within the model, the taxiways are generated using curves and bevels, and later converting into meshes, in a way that needs some manual adjustment before it's ready for navmesh (graph) generation. To use a polyline as a graph for pathfinding would be much easier.

Comment: This sounds the "input" does not change while you are running the game. That provides you with the option to create your "output" within Blender rather than the BGE. E.g. write a Blender script that generates a python file with the data you want. That file is then part of your game (similar to [generate navmesh]). As it is running in Blender you can directly work with curves.

Comment: When you really want it inside the BGE I suggest to extrude all edges. This way you get faces that are loaded into the BGE.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with programming outside the BGE, but i think I understand what you mean. Thank you